# Attach integration to route over CLI in AWS-API-Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, localstack

I created a route and an integration, but I cannot attach the integration to the route using `awscli`. Is this possible to do this over the command line or can it only be done over the web interface?

My goal is to reproduce an existing API-Gateway v2 configuration (that was created using the AWS Web Console) in Localstack Pro, setting it up during container startup so exclusively in using the aws-cli tool.

I can create APIs, routes and integrations without difficulties:

```sh
awslocal apigatewayv2 create-api --name="test-api" --protocol="http"
awslocal apigatewayv2 create-integration --api-id ebb87127 --integration-type AWS --integration-uri arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:some-lambda
awslocal apigatewayv2 create-route --api-id ebb87127 --route-key '$default'
```

but I could not find anything under the `aws apigatewayv2` [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigatewayv2/index.html#cli-aws-apigatewayv2) to link the route to the integration.

Doing it in the "real" AWS is very easy using the web interface:

[image: tab to manage links from routes to integrations]

[image: creating new integration and attaching it directly]

How to achieve this in the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the `--target` option in your "create-route" command. The argument should be `integrations/$INTEGRATION_ID`

```
aws apigatewayv2 create-route --api-id $API_ID --route-key $ROUTE_KEY --target integrations/$INTEGRATION_ID
```